# difference between find and index

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I am new to python and cannot quite understand the difference between find and index.

```
>>> line
'hi, this is ABC oh my god!!'
>>> line.find("o")
16
>>> line.index("o")
16
```

They always return the same result.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 140, accepted):

[`str.find`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) returns `-1` when it does not find the substring.

```
>>> line = 'hi, this is ABC oh my god!!'
>>> line.find('?')
-1
```

While [`str.index`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.index) raises `ValueError`:

```
>>> line.index('?')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: substring not found
```

Both the functions behave the same way if a sub-string is found.

Comment: and if a substring is found, both the functions behave the same way?

Comment: @user1603970, Yes, they do. Their parameters are also same.

Comment: @user1603970, According to the `index` documentation I linked in the answer: Like find(), but raise ValueError when the substring is not found.

Comment: as @reep mentioned,

 find is only available for strings where as index is available for lists, tuples and strings

Comment: python should drop one of these two methods. One of them serve the purpose well. Also i think it's more appropriate for `index` to return `-1` and `find ` return `ValueError` in case `sub` is not found.

Comment: I know its an old comment but since someone upvoted it I have to point out that wanting `list.index` to return `-1` is wrong, as `-1` indicates the last element, negative indexing, the method name index returns an index @pouya

Comment: @python_learner We know both `find` and `index` returns the lowest **positive** index in the string where substring `sub` is found. So a negative index is irrelevant here. Also your logic can be applied to the `find` method as well. Anyway it's better for python to drop `index` in favor of `find` which is better and saner to return `ValueError` in case `sub` is not found.

Comment: I stand by what I said, index is supposed to return an index and in case it did return `-1` it would point to the last element so `ValueError` makes more sense, where as `find` returning `-1` when not found is more to its nature of "finding", the names themselves are clear imo

Comment: ``index`` is a [sequence method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations) with well-defined behaviour, including to raise ``ValueError`` if no match is found: "``index`` raises ``ValueError`` when ``x`` is not found in ``s``." What the specific ``str.find`` method does is entirely inconsequential for the larger picture that ``str.index`` has to be consistent with.

Answer (score 30):

Also find is only available for strings where as index is available for lists, tuples and strings

```
>>> somelist
['Ok', "let's", 'try', 'this', 'out']
>>> type(somelist)
<class 'list'>

>>> somelist.index("try")
2

>>> somelist.find("try")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find'

>>> sometuple
('Ok', "let's", 'try', 'this', 'out')
>>> type(sometuple)
<class 'tuple'>

>>> sometuple.index("try")
2

>>> sometuple.find("try")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'find'

>>> somelist2
"Ok let's try this"
>>> type(somelist2)
<class 'str'>

>>> somelist2.index("try")
9
>>> somelist2.find("try")
9

>>> somelist2.find("t")
5
>>> somelist2.index("t")
5
```

Answer (score 10):

@falsetru provided an explanation about the difference between functions, I did a performance test between them.

```
"""Performance tests of 'find' and 'index' functions.

Results:
using_index t = 0.0259 sec
using_index t = 0.0290 sec
using_index t = 0.6851 sec

using_find t = 0.0301 sec
using_find t = 0.0282 sec
using_find t = 0.6875 sec

Summary:
    Both (find and index) functions have the same performance.
"""


def using_index(text: str, find: str) -> str:
    """Returns index position if found otherwise raises ValueError."""
    return text.index(find)


def using_find(text: str, find: str) -> str:
    """Returns index position if found otherwise -1."""
    return text.find(find)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    from timeit import timeit

    texts = [
        "short text to search" * 10,
        "long text to search" * 10000,
        "long_text_with_find_at_the_end" * 10000 + " to long",
    ]

    for f in [using_index, using_find]:
        for text in texts:
            t = timeit(stmt="f(text, ' ')", number=10000, globals=globals())
            print(f"{f.__name__} {t = :.4f} sec")
        print()
```

Comment: So the more specific `str.find` is not better optimized than `seq.index`. Why not combine both by introducing an argument so that, say, `str.index(sub, panic=False) == str.find(sub)`? :)